# How to query in SQL a particular column with aggregated values in different columns by week?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

Hi this is the 2nd time I'm uploading this. Previously I made some errors. I'm also sharing my solutions and I think it can be made more efficient.
The main question is number 5 which I wonder can be solved in a better way and would appreciate if anyone can come up with something better and also if there are problems which the other answers please highlight the errors

Thanks in advance

Database structure

[image]

use deleted = 0 for all tables as default condition

1. Write a query to display, bottom 2 Cities based on Quantity sold in the last two weeks.

   ```
   WITH 
   t1 AS (SELECT * FROM  "Saleorder Details" WHERE Deleted=0),
   t2 AS (SELECT * FROM "City"),
   t3 AS (SELECT * FROM "Sale order"  WHERE Deleted=0),
   t4 AS (SELECT t1.id,t2.name AS city_name,t1.SkuQuantity FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id),
   t5 AS (SELECT t4.*,t3.DeliveryDate FROM t4 JOIN t3 ON t3.id=t4.id)

   SELECT t5.city_name,t5.SkuQuantity FROM t5 WHERE t5.id =(SELECT t5.id FROM t5 WHERE WEEK(t5.DeliveryDate)=WEEK(NOW())-2) ORDER BY t5.SkuQuantity ASC LIMIT 2
   ```
2. Query to list down SKU wise order count in the last 7 days

   ```
   WITH 
   t1 AS (SELECT * FROM  "Saleorder Details" WHERE Deleted=0),
   t2 AS (SELECT * FROM "Sale order"  WHERE Deleted=0),
   t3 AS (SELECT t1.*,t2.DeliveryDate FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id WHERE t1.id IN (SELECT t2.id FROM t2 WHERE t2.DeliveryDate> NOW() -  INTERVAL 7 DAY),

   t4 AS (SELECT * FROM SKU),
   t5 AS (SELECT t3.*,t4.name FROM t4 JOIN t5 ON t4.id=t5.id)
   SELECT t5.name,COUNT(*) AS order_count FROM t5 GROUP BY   t5.name
   ```
3. Query to list down customer wise, number of full return instances.

   ```
   WITH
   t1 AS (SELECT * FROM  "Saleorder Details" WHERE Deleted=0),
   t2 AS (SELECT * FROM  "Customer" WHERE Deleted=0),
   t3 AS (SELECT t2.*,t1.* FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id WHERE t1.ReturnQuantity IS NOT NULL OR ReturnQuantity !=0)
   SELECT t3.name,COUNT(*) AS number of RETURNS FROM t3 GROUP BY name
   ```
4. Query to list down City wise, facility wise average order values greater than 200.

   ```
   WITH 
   t1 AS (SELECT * FROM  "Saleorder Details" WHERE Deleted=0),
   t2 AS (SELECT * FROM  "Sale order" WHERE Deleted=0),
   t3 AS (SELECT t1.*,t2.* FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id),
   t4 AS (SELECT * FROM City),
   t5 AS (SELECT t3.*,t4.Name AS city_name FROM t4 JOIN t3 ON t4.id=t3.id)

   SELECT DISTINCT* FROM (SELECT t5.city_name,t5.FacilityId FROM t5 WHERE AVG(t5.SalePrice)>200) AS cte
   ```
5. Query to list down Facility wise revenue for the past three weeks in the below mention format.

   | FACILITY_ID | CURRENT WEEK | LAST WEEK |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | Revenue |  |  |

   ```
   WITH 
   t1 AS (SELECT * FROM  "Saleorder Details" WHERE Deleted=0),  
   t2 AS (SELECT * FROM  "Sale order" WHERE Deleted=0),
   t3 AS (SELECT t1.*,t2.* FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id),

   SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (SELECT t3.FacilityId,(SELECT SUM(SalePrice*SkuQuantity) FROM t3 AS a WHERE WEEK(t3.DeliveryDate)=WEEK(NOW()) AND a.FacilityId=d.FacilityId GROUP BY t3.FacilityId) AS 'Current Week',
                            (SELECT   SUM(SalePrice*SkuQuantity) FROM t3 AS b WHERE WEEK(t3.DeliveryDate)=WEEK(NOW())-1 AND b.FacilityId=d.FacilityId GROUP BY t3.FacilityId) AS 'Last Week',
                             (SELECT SUM(SalePrice*SkuQuantity) FROM t3 AS c WHERE WEEK(t3.DeliveryDate)=WEEK(NOW())-2 AND c.FacilityId=d.FacilityId GROUP BY t3.FacilityId) AS '3rd  Week'
                        FROM t3 AS d) AS cte
   ```

Comment: Hi - you don’t seem to have actually asked a question. I assume you are not expecting someone to review all your homework questions and correct them?

Comment: Hi @James Z  I have asked a question on number 5 which I have solved it but I wonder whether there are better ways to solve it.

Comment: It was @NickW who asked that question, not me. And you didn't ask a question, you just listed the questions someone asked from you.